# How to do instancing the right way in OpenGL.

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, gpu

I am trying to use VBO and Instancing mechanism the most efficent way. I have a world based on voxels and I would like to draw them using least possible number of draw-calls. The code below prepares VBO with a quad:

```
void VoxelView::initVBOs() {
/*--------------------- Main OpenGL Program ---------------------*/
/* Vertices of a triangle (counter-clockwise winding) */
float data[6][3] = {
                                            // Left bottom triangle
                                            { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f  },
                                            { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f },
                                            { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f  },
                                            // Right top triangle
                                            { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f  },
                                            { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f   },
                                            { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f  }

                                       };

/*---------------------- Initialise VBO - (Note: do only once, at start of program) ---------------------*/
/* Create a new VBO and use the variable "triangleVBO" to store the VBO id */
glGenBuffers(1, &triangleVBO);

/* Make the new VBO active */
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVBO);

/* Upload vertex data to the video device */
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * 3 * sizeof(float), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

/* Specify that our coordinate data is going into attribute index 0(shaderAttribute), and contains three floats per vertex */
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

/* Enable attribute index 0(shaderAttribute) as being used */
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderAttribute);

/* Make the new VBO active. */
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVBO);

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------- Load Vertex and Fragment shaders from files and compile them --------------------*/
/* Read our shaders into the appropriate buffers */
vertexSource = filetobuf("Shaders/exampleVertexShader1.vert");
fragmentSource = filetobuf("Shaders/exampleFragmentShader1.frag");

/* Assign our handles a "name" to new shader objects */
vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

/* Associate the source code buffers with each handle */
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertexSource, 0);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar**)&fragmentSource, 0);

/* Free the temporary allocated memory */
free(vertexSource);
free(fragmentSource);

/* Compile our shader objects */
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*-------------------- Create shader program, attach shaders to it and then link it ---------------------*/
/* Assign our program handle a "name" */
shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

/* Attach our shaders to our program */
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

/* Bind attribute index 0 (shaderAttribute) to in_Position*/
/* "in_Position" will represent "data" array's contents in the vertex shader */
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, shaderAttribute, "in_Position");

/* Link shader program*/
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
```

I am rendering the quad the following way:

```
void VoxelView::renderVBO()
{
/* Set shader program as being actively used */
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

/* Set background colour to BLACK */
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

/* Clear background with BLACK colour */
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/* Actually draw the triangle, giving the number of vertices provided by invoke glDrawArrays
   while telling that our data is a triangle and we want to draw 0-3 vertexes
*/
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

I would like to draw this quad (which uses VBO) multiple times using the instancing mechanizm. I would like it to fe fairly simple as I want to implement it for more sophisticated code. I know that I should use **glDrawElementsInstanced** method to use instancing but I don't know how to do it. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Always include your OpenGL version in future... it makes an enormous difference as you probably know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using glDrawElementsInstanced you need to make your shaders use gl_InstanceiD

```
#version 410

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position; 
layout (location = 1) in vec2 TexCoord; 
layout (location = 2) in vec3 Normal; 
layout (location = 3) in mat4 WVP; 
layout (location = 7) in mat4 World; 

out vec2 TexCoord0; 
out vec3 Normal0; 
out vec3 WorldPos0; 
flat out int InstanceID; 

void main() 
{ 
    gl_Position = WVP * vec4(Position, 1.0); 
    TexCoord0 = TexCoord; 
    Normal0 = World * vec4(Normal, 0.0)).xyz; 
    WorldPos0 = World * vec4(Position, 1.0)).xyz; 
    InstanceID = gl_InstanceID; 
};
```

`glDrawElementsInstanced` use gl_InstanceID variable as if it were a static integer vertex attribute. When the first copy of the vertices is sent to OpenGL,
`gl_InstanceID` will be zero. It will then be incremented once for each copy of the geometry and will eventually reach instanceCount - 1.

It behaves like this

```
for (int n = 0; n < instancecount; n++)
{
// Set the value of gl_InstanceID
glVertexAttrib1i(gl_InstanceID, n); // except this is internally incremented and not a real vertex attribute
// Make a normal call to glDrawElements
glDrawElements(mode, count, type, indices);
}
```

Except that this happens internally, and you only need to call `glDrawArraysInstanced()` once. In order to use different transforms for each instance you can pass an array of uniform matrices and index that using `gl_InstanceID` or you can use texture buffer objects and store transforms there.

So your drawing code should become like this, but note that you still need to pass uniform matrices for each intsance in an array or pass a texture buffer object once for all.

```
glDrawElementsInstanced(primitivetype, indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, instanceCount-1);
```

and your vertex shader should become

```
uniform mat4 instancematrices[32];

void main()
{
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * instancematrices[gl_InstanceID] * gl_Vertex;
}
```

Comment: OK, but what when I want to join both instancing using shaders and VBO. Are those techniques complementary or there are exclusive? I have to use **glDrawArrays** insetad of **glDrawElementsInstanced**. I have no clue how to do it the apropriate way.

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski the only drawing method in modern openGL is using VBOs. glDrawArrays actually needs a VBO to be bind, and you need to repeat it multiple times in order to draw the same geometry multiple times. You can `glDrawElementsInstanced` or `glDrawArraysInstanced` as they are only an alternaitve method to draw VBOs. As I said in the answer instead of using glDrawElement/Arrays in loop you use glDrawArraysInstanced or glDrawElementsInstanced one time. I hope it's clear

Comment: So, if I understand correctly **glDrawArraysInstanced** is a way of drawing the instanced VBOs.

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski yes

Comment: Thanks, I also found a good example of using instancing and VBO and now I will try to join the knowledge I gained.

Comment: It's really bad practice to use deprecated features like `gl_Vertex` in SO answers... it can set newbies on the wrong path in their goal of learning modern OpenGL. Also, you should be using the later features like `ARB_instanced_arrays` (OpenGL 3.3) -- the uniforms approach via `gl_InstanceID` is both slower than using vertex attributes / VBOs and is also limited by `MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS`, the maximum size of uniforms per shader program (typically 512-1024 floats, which is actually quite insufficient when you consider that instancing counts can easily run into the tens of thousands).

Comment: for those who landed at this outdated answer (like me) looking OpenGL instanced rendering: google for **glVertexAttribDivisor**